# Regex Expression with the JQ Tool

Tags: regex, jq

I have a json file which I am using the JQ tool on to get a some lines out of it. However I now need to get some information out of this line using regex. I stuck on two parts. The first bit is that I can't figure out the regular expression to get the lines I want and the second issues is that I do now know what the correct syntax is to apply the regex along with the JQ Tool. I have tried the following syntax and get the error of "unterminated regexp"

```
jq '.msg.stdout_lines[2]' /tmp/vaultKeys.json | awk '{gsub(/\:(.*[\a-zA-Z0-9]))}1'
```

My json file is as follows:

```
{
"msg": {
"changed": true,
"cmd": [
  "vault",
  "operator",
  "init"
],
"delta": "0:00:00.568974",
"end": "2018-11-29 15:42:00.243019",
"failed": false,
"rc": 0,
"start": "2018-11-29 15:41:59.674045",
"stderr": "",
"stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "Unseal Key 1: ZA0Gas2GrHtdMlet1g63N6gvEPYf5mzZEfjPhMDRyAeS\nUnseal Key 2: NY+CLIbgMJIv+e81FuB1OpV0m7rPuqZbIuYT142MrQLl\nUnseal Key 3: HNWmsrXBsSV9JFuGfqpd+GvPYQzHEsLFlxKBfEyBhCZ6\nUnseal Key 4: xDwfI+kFHFRSzq2JyxSGArQsGjCrFiNbkGCP897Zfbuz\nUnseal Key 5: +O8/tTmDNSzaUBMT8QP+2xbvu5uulypf3+xmWzY8fSD3\n\nInitial Root Token: 6kO8ijZzyhcG5Nup5QUca0u3\n\nVault initialized with 5 key shares and a key threshold of 3. Please securely\ndistribute the key shares printed above. When the Vault is re-sealed,\nrestarted, or stopped, you must supply at least 3 of these keys to unseal it\nbefore it can start servicing requests.\n\nVault does not store the generated master key. Without at least 3 key to\nreconstruct the master key, Vault will remain permanently sealed!\n\nIt is possible to generate new unseal keys, provided you have a quorum of\nexisting unseal keys shares. See \"vault operator rekey\" for more information.",
"stdout_lines": [
  "Unseal Key 1: ZA0Gas2GrHtdMlet1g63N6gvEPYf5mzZEfjPhMDRyAeS",
  "Unseal Key 2: NY+CLIbgMJIv+e81FuB1OpV0m7rPuqZbIuYT142MrQLl",
  "Unseal Key 3: HNWmsrXBsSV9JFuGfqpd+GvPYQzHEsLFlxKBfEyBhCZ6",
  "Unseal Key 4: xDwfI+kFHFRSzq2JyxSGArQsGjCrFiNbkGCP897Zfbuz",
  "Unseal Key 5: +O8/tTmDNSzaUBMT8QP+2xbvu5uulypf3+xmWzY8fSD3",
  "",
  "Initial Root Token: 6kO8ijZzyhcG5Nup5QUca0u3",
  "",
  "Vault initialized with 5 key shares and a key threshold of 3. Please securely",
  "distribute the key shares printed above. When the Vault is re-sealed,",
  "restarted, or stopped, you must supply at least 3 of these keys to unseal it",
  "before it can start servicing requests.",
  "",
  "Vault does not store the generated master key. Without at least 3 key to",
  "reconstruct the master key, Vault will remain permanently sealed!",
  "",
  "It is possible to generate new unseal keys, provided you have a quorum of",
  "existing unseal keys shares. See \"vault operator rekey\" for more information."
 ]
}
}
```

Out of the line

```
"Unseal Key 3: HNWmsrXBsSV9JFuGfqpd+GvPYQzHEsLFlxKBfEyBhCZ6"
```

I would like just

```
HNWmsrXBsSV9JFuGfqpd+GvPYQzHEsLFlxKBfEyBhCZ6
```

Currently using my regex I get only if I use it without the JQ tool syntax

```
: ZA0Gas2GrHtdMlet1g63N6gvEPYf5mzZEfjPhMDRyAeS
```

So to summarise I need help with

a) getting a correct regular expression and

b) the correct syntax to use the expression with the JQ Tool.

Thanks

Comment: Hey @oguzismail. Thanks for the answer it worked like a charm. Could you put it as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case you can use split instead of regex.

```
jq -r '.msg.stdout_lines[2]|split(" ")[-1]' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have GNU `grep`?

```
jq -r '.msg.stdout_lines[2]' /tmp/vaultKeys.json | grep -Po '(?<=: ).+'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of one-stop shopping, you could for example use this invocation:

```
jq -r '.msg.stdout_lines[2]
       | capture(": (?<s>.*)").s'
```

Of course there are many other possibilities, depending on your precise requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, besides the obvious `| grep -Po '(?<=: ).+\b'` you could even use substr with awk if the string length is fixed:

```
jq .. | awk '{print substr($1, RSTART+14)}'
```